# How to rewrite code in order for the code to be dry in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dry

I am relatively new to react and wanted to know how I could rewrite this code in order for it to be dry. as you can see the cardcontent and typography is pretty much the same, but the only difference is the `<Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>` and `<Typography variant="body2" component="p">`

```
  <div className={styles.container}>
      <Grid container spacing={3} justify="center">
        <Grid item component={Card} xs={12} md={3} className={cx(styles.card, styles.infected)}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
              Infected
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
              <CountUp
                start={0}
                end={confirmed.value}
                duration={2.5}
                separator=","
              />
            </Typography>
            <Typography color="textSecondary">
              {new Date(lastUpdate).toDateString()}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
              Number of active cases of COVID-19
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item component={Card} xs={12} md={3} className={cx(styles.card, styles.recovered)}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
              Recovered
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
              <CountUp
                start={0}
                end={recovered.value}
                duration={2.75}
                separator=","
              />
            </Typography>
            <Typography color="textSecondary">
              {new Date(lastUpdate).toDateString()}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2">
              Number of recoveries from COVID-19
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item component={Card} xs={12} md={3} className={cx(styles.card, styles.deaths)}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
              Deaths
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
              <CountUp
                start={0}
                end={deaths.value}
                duration={2.75}
                separator=","
              />
            </Typography>
            <Typography color="textSecondary">
              {new Date(lastUpdate).toDateString()}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2">
              Number of deaths caused by COVID-19
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you're just worried about the `Typography` component, and it's just there to add appropriate markup/styles to various text, I'm not sure you really need to change anything. Repeating heavy code is generally bad but honestly this is more like repeating (similar but not identical) markup, and in that situation I'd take "keep it simple" over "don't repeat yourself" every time.

Comment: I would move the entire Grid item to a seperate component. So that one change (say: change of breakpoint, or changing the variant) has to be done only at single place.

Answer (score 0):

You could simple map around the data to render the Grid->Card->Typography Components assuming if you could extract the data and maintain it in your state or pass it through props. Either way is fine.

```
const data = [{
  type: 'infected',
  displayName: 'Infected',
  count: {
    start: 0
  },
  duration: 2.5,
  displayStatusText: 'Number of active cases of COVID-19',
},
{
  type: 'recovered',
  displayName: 'Recovered',
  count: {
    start: 0
  },
  duration: 2.5,
  displayStatusText: 'Number of recoveries from COVID-19',
},
{
  type: 'infected',
  displayName: 'Infected',
  count: {
    start: 0
  },
  duration: 2.5,
  displayStatusText: 'Number of deaths caused by COVID-19',
}];
```

And in the return of the render method you can map the component this way

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <Grid container spacing={3} justify="center">
          {this.state.data.map((item, i) => {
            return (
              <Grid key={i} item component={Card} xs={12} md={3}
                className={cx(styles.card, item.type === 'infected' ? styles.infected : item.type === 'recovered' ? styles.recovered : styles.deaths)}>
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                    {item.type}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                    <CountUp start={item.count.start} end={item.type === 'infected' ? confirmed.value : item.type === 'recovered' ? recovered.value : deaths.value} duration={item.duration} separator="," />
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography color="textSecondary">
                    {new Date(lastUpdate).toDateString()}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
                    {item.displayStatusText}
                  </Typography>
                </CardContent>
              </Grid>
            );
          })}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

The only catch here is that you should notice how the className and end attributes get the values based on how the ternary operator evaluates.